# Alow only Integer and Float values in Textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textfield of **Price**.

I want only Integer and Float values in it.

I have done the Integer. But it is not accepting Float values like : 3110.6

Here is my Code [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jVMUR/)

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#price").keydown(function (event) {
        // Allow only backspace and delete
        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
        } else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input name="price" type="text" id="price">
```

Comment: `if(isNaN(parseFloat(...)) || isNaN(parseInt(..., 10))`

Comment: `<input type="number" ...`

Comment: Update fiddle please ?

Answer (score 2):

try this  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/har1236/79BSM/)

```
 $('#price').keypress(function(event) {
            if(event.which == 8 || event.which == 0){
                return true;
            }
            if(event.which < 46 || event.which > 59) {
                return false;
                //event.preventDefault();
            } // prevent if not number/dot

            if(event.which == 46 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) {
                return false;
                //event.preventDefault();
            } // prevent if already dot
        });
```

Comment: price can not be negative

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

```
<input name="price" type="number" id="price">
```

And remove your JavaScript code.

Comment: How you you input a decimal?

Answer (score 1):

Try regular expression

```
/^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Just test the value of the input on the onchange event.

Comment: And then do what? You have to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

TRy [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/jVMUR/1/) dot or period has keycode 190

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#price").keydown(function(event) {
    // Allow only backspace and delete
    if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ||  event.keyCode == 190 ) {
        // let it happen, don't do anything
    }
    else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

But better will be use jquery validator plugin at http://jqueryvalidation.org/ as you dont have to check yourself.

For jquery version see [JQUERY VALIDATION](http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/jVMUR/4/)

Comment: TRy http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/jVMUR/3/ But i remind you you should use validator plugin its still bettter.